# How to apply a list comprehension in Panda Dataframe?

Tags: pandas, list, list-comprehension

From a `list` of values, I try to identify any sequential pair of values whose sum exceeds 10

```
a = [1,9,3,4,5]
```

...so I wrote a `for` loop...

```
values = []
for i in range(len(a)-2):
    if sum(a[i:i+2]) >10:
        values += [a[i:i+2]]
```

...which I rewritten as a list comprehension...

```
values = [a[i:i+2] for i in range(len(a)-2) if sum(a[i:i+2]) >10]
```

Both produce same output:

```
values = [[1,9], [9,3]]
```

My question is how best may I apply the above list comprehension in a DataFrame.

Here is the sample 5 rows DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,1,0], 
                   'B': [9,8,3,2,2],
                   'C': [3,3,3,10,3],
                   'E': [4,4,4,4,4],
                   'F': [5,5,5,5,5]})
df['X'] = df.values.tolist()
```

where: 
- a is within a `df['X']` which is a list of values Columns A - F

```
df['X'] = [[1,9,3,4,5],[1,8,3,4,5],[1,3,3,4,5],[1,2,10,4,5],[0,2,3,4,5]]
```

- and, result of the list comprehension is to be store in new column `df['X1]`

Desired output is:

```
df['X1'] = [[[1,9], [9,3]],[[8,3]],[[NaN]],[[2,10],[10,4]],[[NaN]]]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please set up a small sample dataframe for the input and one for the desired output.

Comment: You can check out [this reference post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) if you have trouble setting up sample dataframes.

Comment: Thanks. Added sample dataframe

Comment: That sample dataframe is a bit too large to work with. Can you limit it to six rows with deterministic (not randomly generated) values, please? Also, please post the **result** you want for that sample. Thanks.

Comment: By the way I need to see the desired result here because it is not clear how you want the new column to fit into the original dataframe. Because your code can produce a list shorter than the original column.

Comment: Just to store the results in a new column

Comment: What if the result is shorter than the other columns?

Comment: NaN. df['X1'] is a list of list.

Comment: Let me re-create the sample dataframe.....

Comment: @denpy In your desired output the `values >= 10` are included but in your list comprehension you specify `values > 10` should be included?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use pandas apply function, and put your list comprehension in it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,1,0], 
                   'B': [9,8,3,2,2],
                   'C': [3,3,3,10,3],
                   'E': [4,4,4,4,4],
                   'F': [5,5,5,5,5]})

df['x'] = df.apply(lambda a: [a[i:i+2] for i in range(len(a)-2) if sum(a[i:i+2]) >= 10], axis=1)

#Note the axis parameters tells if you want to apply this function by rows or by columns, axis = 1 applies the function to each row.
```

This will give the output as stated in df['X1']