# how to replace itrerows function in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how to replace itrerows function in pandas dataframe

```
for index, row in new_frame.iterrows():
    new_frame.at[index, 'image'] = ('{0}{1}_1.jpg'.format(image_folder, 
                                                           str(row.Code)))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply a list comprehension in Panda Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62118556/how-to-apply-a-list-comprehension-in-panda-dataframe)

Comment: No i didn't because i faild i try with itertuples :    for row in new_frame.itertuples():
        new_frame.at[row.index, 'image'] = ('{0}{1}_1.jpg'.format(image_folder, str(row.Code))) but i got an other probleme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show any sample data, but it seems you could use

```
new_frame['image'] = image_folder + new_frame['Code'].astype(str) + '_1.jpg'
```

Assuming `image_folder` is a string

Comment: yes image_folder  is a string (path to image folder)

Comment: your syntax work fine  Thank you Is there anny why to add image to dataframe when export it to excel?

Comment: You want to insert an image object into an excel sheet? I haven't done that with python, but google xlwings I guess